# Update a Label in a View when application: openURL: sourceApplication: annotaion: is called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm struggling with following problem:

I am using the Method

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

to set a Serverstring from extern. So when i do call myapp://serverurl/url the string *url* is set correctly to a *NSUSerDefaults Key*. That works fine so far.
But when I am currently in the Settingsview of my App, where you can set this variable manually and i call the above url for example from the Mail-App, it sets the variable, but the corresponding Textfield of the View is not updated. So the old string is still written in the Textfield but in *NSUSerDefaults* its updated correctly.

I tried to work with the Notification Center. I bound the the following Method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateServerURLTextField) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

- (void)updateServerURLTextField
{
    NSLog(@"Updating Serveraddress label");
    NSString* serverFullURL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:wServerFullURLKey];
    self.serverURLTextField.text = serverFullUrl;
}
```

The Notification gets fired so does *updateServerURLTextField* but its not updated. I assume some race time conditions?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

gets called after the Notification is fired. Maybe the GUI cant be updated before the App is active?

Anyone got some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the UI this way. All changes to UI need to happen on the main thread. You might consider using: [`PerformSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)

Comment: All right. Changed the Observer Method to a simple Method called update in which i call `PerformSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` with the updateServerURLTextField-Method. Works so far. Feels a bit dirty somehow ;)

Comment: I am not sure what the rest of your program looks like but this might be a candidate for Key Value Observing.